# I want to return Integer in my Code from Stored Procedure without modifying my Stored Procedure

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core, stored-procedures

But I'm getting an exception

> Required column was not present in 'FromSql' operation

This is my stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[CIT_UpdateContentSetDetailsProcessStatusByBuildId] 
    @Id BIGINT, 
    @BuildId VARCHAR(100), 
    @SourceId INT
AS 
BEGIN 
    SET NOCOUNT ON; 

    IF (@BuildId IS NOT NULL AND @BuildId != '' AND @BuildId != 'Pending')
    BEGIN
        UPDATE [citcontentsetdetails] 
        SET processstatus = 101 
        WHERE id IN (SELECT CSD.id 
                     FROM [citcontentsetdetails] CSD 
                     JOIN citbuilddetails BD ON BD.contentsetdetailsid = CSD.id 
                     JOIN citbuild B ON B.id = BD.buildid 
                     WHERE B.buildid = @BuildId AND SourceId = @SourceId) 
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        UPDATE [citcontentsetdetails] 
        SET processstatus = 101 
        WHERE id IN (SELECT CSD.id 
                     FROM [citcontentsetdetails] CSD 
                     JOIN citbuilddetails BD ON BD.contentsetdetailsid = CSD.id 
                     JOIN citbuild B ON B.id = BD.buildid 
                     WHERE B.Id = @Id) 
    END

    SELECT 1 
END
```

My code:

```
public void UpdateProcessStatusByBuildId(BuildIDDetailDTO buildDetailsData)
{
    List<BuildIDDetailResultDto> source = new List<BuildIDDetailResultDto>();
    int result;

    Contract.Requires(buildDetailsData != null);

    try
    {       
        if (buildDetailsData != null)
        {
             const string defaultId = "@Id";
             const string defaultbuildId = "@BuildId";
             const string defaultSourceId = "@SourceId";

             using (var _context = _contextFactory.CreateDbContext())
             {
                 result =_context.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw("CIT_UpdateContentSetDetailsProcessStatusByBuildId @Id={0}, @BuildId={1},@SourceId={2} ", buildDetailsData.Id, buildDetailsData.BuildId, buildDetailsData.SourceId);
             }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

Comment: Which table does the `SourceId` belong to? https://i.stack.imgur.com/aLqdN.png

Comment: It belongs to CITBuild Table

Comment: Can you figure out if the stored procedure or the c# code lead to the problem?

Comment: Hi Tiny Wang, I got it fixed Anyway Thanks.

Comment: It was my C# error. The SP cannot go wrong as it was a revamp and the SP is running in the old application.